# setText in a ListFragment

Tags: android, textview, fragment, loader

I'm a beginner at Android programming and I was wondering if you could help me out.

I have a ListFragment:

```
public class AdvertFrag extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
```

that I'm populating from a database using a loaderManager. This works fine and displays details of adverts, but I would like to do some calculations (work out distance via longitude and latitude) and then have the distance to the shops location displayed on each AdvertFrag.

I have looked into using setText() on a TextView in a fragment and have read you should allow the onCreateView method to be called first so a view is present. I have tried the below code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, container, false);
        if(view == null)
        {
            Log.i("TEST","null");
        }
        else
        {
            distance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.distance);
            distance.setText("the distance will go here");
        }
        return view;
    }
```

But get the error that "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is android.R.id.list. Allowing the OnCreateView to just call:

```
return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

works fine.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong? and how do I get setText working in a ListActivity? Or am i going at it in totally the wrong way?

**Addition info if its useful:**

My row.xml, just has the text views that are populated by the loader and the additional textview for the distance.

I have a fragmentActivity that has the fragment in its XML, like so:

```
<fragment 
        ...
        android:name="com.example.goclub.AdvertFrag"
        .../>
```

Comment: Overriding `onCreateView()` of the `ListFragment` would mean you want to show a different layout for the whole fragment (e.g., stuff below/above the list). This isn't the place to manage the layout for the individual list items.

Comment: +1 for good question: you wrote it very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like user113215 said `onCreateView()` of the `ListFragment` is not a place to change widgets inside the list items. You will have to create a custom `CursorAdapter` for that assuming that you are using one. You can find a nice tutorial about this [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/). Basically it extends a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and makes changes in the `bindView` method.

Comment: Brilliant. I followed that tutorial and got it working. Thanks for your help.